# VBA sql query based off combobox

Tags: sql-server, vba, combobox, ado

I've been searching hard the past few days and have come across numerous examples that outline what I'm trying to do.  However, I can't seem to get this working.  I have a combobox that populates data (a company name) from a table when the form initializes.  I then want to take the value chosen in the combo box and run another query to cross reference an id number in that same table.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()



    Dim myCn As MyServer
    Set myCn = New MyServer

    Dim rs As ADODB.recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.recordset

    Dim sqlStr As String
    Dim CompField As String

    'CompField = ComboBox1.Value



    sqlStr = "SELECT DISTINCT [acctno] FROM client WHERE [company] = '" & ComboBox1.Text & "'"

    'sqlStr = "Select DISTINCT [company] FROM client;"

   ' sqlStr = "SELECT DISTINCT [acctno] FROM client WHERE [company] = " & UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value & ";"

    'sqlStr = "SELECT DISTINCT [acctno] FROM client WHERE [company] = " & UserForm1.ComboBox1.Text & ";"

    'sqlStr = "SELECT DISTINCT [acctno] FROM client WHERE [company] = 'Company XYZ';"

    'sqlStr = "SELECT DISTINCT [acctno] FROM client WHERE company = " & CompField & ""



    rs.Open sqlStr, myCn.GetConnection, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

     MsgBox sqlStr
    'MsgBox ComboBox1.Value
    'MsgBox rs(0)



    rs.Close
    myCn.Shutdown

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set myCn = Nothing


End Sub
```

Currently with the combobox value encased in single quotes i get the entire sql string returned.  If I remove the single quotes I get a syntax error referencing part of the combobox value.  All other efforts have resulted in run-time errors that have led me nowhere.

I know my query works because I've tested it in SQL Studio and if I hard code a text value in this code I also get the Account ID I'm looking for.  Not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: You need to read up about sql injection. Your query is a textbook example of how not to write a query. You should never directly execute a sql string built up from user input. This should be parameterized or moved to a stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Since I'm the only one who will be using this code I don't have much of a concern for anyone doing any type of SQL injection attack.  And while I would agree with you I feel a SP would be a tad overkill for my purposes.  So while I appreciate the insight I'll hope that someone else can provide additional info on why my code isn't working.

Comment: I didn't say it would be overkill. I would parameterize the queries even if I was the only one using it. It is easier to debug imho. I don't know the exact reason your code isn't working because there are many details not shared here. It does seem a little suspect that you are passing the text of your combobox instead of the value. That may well be the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I figured what I stated with my code would be good for starters.  I'm currently looking into parametrizing the query so hopefully that will get me somewhere.  Also, I have tried passing value instead of text and it's no difference.  For example, the first company in the combo list is "Six Hartford", whether I pass that as value or text I get "Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)': Incorrect syntax near Hartford".   It's always throwing the syntax error near the second word of whatever value is being passed from the combo box.

Comment: What you need to do is capture the value in your sql variable and determine why you are getting a syntax error. It is obvious from the message that your sql string is invalid. Maybe you are passing in a value with a single tick mark in it? You aren't escaping those so maybe that is the issue. I am shooting in the dark.

Comment: That will work until you run into a value with a ' in it. Then you are right back here with your query crashing again. If you would parameterize this instead that problem will go away and you will be 100% safe from sql injection. You really need to research how to use parameters in your sql. It is a LOT easier once you do it a couple times and your code is better for it.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out. I was expecting to be able to MsgBox the variable assigned to the SQL query and see my results. But it doesn't work that way. I had to use ADO GetString method for that and assign another variable. Oh and you were right about escaping, I had to add delimters to properly handle the ComboBox value in the query which ultimately looked like this

`sqlStr = "SELECT DISTINCT [acct_no] FROM client WHERE [company] = " & Chr(39) & Me.ComboBox1.Value & Chr(39)`

Thanks for your help on this